# invalid charecter for single quotes for sql string in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting the "Invalid character constant" due to single quot in java sql string, i need double quote which i have put in single quote

```
new StringBuffer("SELECT REPLACE(u.nombre,',',' ') as Organizacion,  ")
    .append(" CONCAT(' " ',REPLACE(s.direccion,',',' '),'"') as Street, '""' as Street2,")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape quotes in java string literals :

```
.append(" CONCAT('\"',REPLACE(s.direccion,',',' '),'\"') as Street, '\"\"' as Street2,")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `"` in the string but the problem is you did not escape it causing to break the whole string.

You need to escape it using `\`, ex.

```
" CONCAT('\"',REPLACE(s.direccion,',',' '),'\"') as Street, '\"\"' as Street2,"
```