# JAVA update statement using WHERE and a variable: invalid character constant

Tags: java, sql

just kinda struggling with identifying the id during the piece update. I pass the id as a var and am trying to use it in conjunction with the WHERE statement and cant seem to figure out the correct syntax

```
String update = "UPDATE LawnMowers"+ " SET LMPrice = '"+returnedPrice+"' " + " WHERE LMID = '"+returnedID+'";
```

the return id is the issue, and the error is "invalid character constant".  I believe the issue is normally the statement would be:

"WHERE LMID = int/double.ect"; rather then using " WHERE LMID = '"+varr+'"; errors and adding the additional " or )" ect options I have tried dont work either. Just wondering if any one had some insight

my DB is on Godaddy

thanks for reading

Comment: You are missing an " at the end, is that intentional?

Comment: using the " after the +' " still errors the same

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871302/invalid-charecter-for-single-quotes-for-sql-string-in-java

Comment: You should use bind variables and a PreparedStatement to eliminate the possibility of SQL injection and the need to juggle with the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statement should end

```
+ returnedID + "'";
```

Yours currently ends

```
+returnedID+'";
```

Also please read about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), these are much easier to use and leave you at far less risk of SQLi security vulnerabilities. It would look something like this:

```
String update = "UPDATE LawnMowers SET LMPrice = ? WHERE LMID = ?";
updateStatement = con.prepareStatement(update);
updateStatement.setInt(1, returnedPrice);
updateStatement.setInt(2, returnedId);
updateStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: There you go! thanks, soon as i have 15 rep ill be upvoting, else if some one could give David one for me that would be great

Comment: @KassadHyperion Even with 1 rep you can still accept an answer if it has helped you.